# Training word2vec on hadoop cluster

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark, word2vec

When trying to training a Word2vec model, I get the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o106.trainWord2VecModel.
: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
```

I tried to limit the growth of the vectors to stay within the bounds of the maximum of an integer according to the following formula:

```
featureSize = (maxIntSize / 8)/vocabulary size
```

Where:

```
maxIntsize/8 = 268435455
```

in my case.

And:

```
vocabulary size = 1811786
```

And thus the feature vector size is set at:

```
148
```

Leaving enough discriminative power for my task whilst not stepping out of the bounds of the systems array size.

My settings are:

```
conf = (SparkConf()
.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "0")\
.set("driver-memory", "50g")\
.set("executor-memory", "6g")\
.set("num-executors", "400"))
```

Increasing the executor-memory does not seem to help...

Googling nor asking the cluster consultants seem to know how to solve it.

Comment: you might consider a java impl of word2vec: http://deeplearning4j.org/word2vec
it's certified on CDH and HDP.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I saw it before, do you think is really matters? Python simple calls underlying functions ... How would this affect array size limit?

Comment: The Python wrapper will slow you down there. Our impl of word2vec is pretty well documented, can handle large models, and there's a community of users talking about it here: https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j

Comment: @tremstat I'm curious: how do you certify a framework against CDH/HDP?  And what does that really mean?

Comment: it means you run your software in conjunction with parts of CDH or HDP, you show Cloudera or Hortonworks the results and document the process, and satisfy any questions they may have. basically, certification means that you have done the preliminary work of ensuring that your software plays nicely with these other distros, so that the end users have an easier time using both...